# Mysterious inadequate stack traces in XCode give no context to where the error is occurring

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm running into lots of instances with the latest version(s) of XCode (I believe this has been happening since 4.2 or so) where the stack trace when an exception is thrown is woefully devoid of details.

The screeshot here illustrates one such case; in fact, this scenario at least has *SOME* context (it shows me that it happened in the JKArray class), where many times I get nothing but "internal" stack items (just 2-3 entries in the thread, none of which reside in user code or anything I can look at). Even in this example, I don't know where the JKArray was allocated or released, so I have no idea what instance or where the problem is.

[image]

Thoughts:

- I've tried adding a generic "on exception" breakpoint
- There is some minor information available in the output; in this case: " malloc: *** error for object 0x10e18120: pointer being freed was not allocated *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug". Doing this doesn't get me any further, though, since the breakpoint gets hit in the same stack as the exception...
- I've tried switching to the other debugger
- I've tried using my own custom exception handler
- I've tried using the Profiler to look for leaks. There are no leaks that I can find.

No matter what I do, I can't seem to isolate the issues plaguing my app. Furthermore, the issues do not seem to be exactly the same each time, likely due to the high amount of concurrency in my app... so I'm left without a good way to fix the problems.

---

Edit: in the case of this particular exception, I did end up finding the cause. I had attempted to [release] and object that was [autoreleased]d. However, all of this was happening within my code; I can't understand why XCode would not give me a decent stack trace to help me find the problem, rather than forcing me to hunt through my whole app...

Comment: Just to be sure, did you try to debug using NSZombie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it is impossible to pinpoint the real problem, because the issue that causes the symptom has happened much earlier.

Your issue provides a great example: when you release your object, cocoa has no idea that you've done anything wrong: you are releasing an object that you own, this is precisely what you should be doing, so there's no red flags. The code that leads to a breakdown is executed well after your method has finished, and gave the control back to the run loop. It is at this point that the run loop gets around to draining its autorelease pool, causing the second deallocation. All it knows at this point, however, is that the run loop has made an invalid deallocation, not your code. By the time the error happens the culprit is safely off the stack (and off the hook), so there is nothing else Xcode can report back to you.

A solution to problems like this is to profile your memory use: the profiler should catch issues like that, and pinpoint the places where they happen.

It goes without saying that switching to automatic reference counting will save you lots of troubles in the memory management department.

Comment: Fair points all around. I at least expected, though, to have SOME context... but I guess it is not always possible. Go figure that all the bugs that plague me are of this sort ;) That said, the profiler is not catching these issues :( And ARC isn't really an option for me on this project.

Comment: @ZaneClaes Unfortunately, C derivatives suffer from the absence of "fail fast" exceptions a lot: undefined behavior often manifests itself much later, and very often it does so in really unexpected places. I take this as a cost of accessing the super-low overhead associated with C/Objective C/C++, a fair tradeoff when any additional overhead is subtracted directly from your user's battery life :)